# laravel query returns empty with escape character

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using laravel framework to develop API's, and database is an mysql.i am writing a following query it's showing empty results but data is present

```
$data = User::where('linkedModel','App\Models\Settings');
```

after research i was trying with following way but still it's showing empty results,can any one give me some idea how to make it work.

```
$data = User::where('linkedModel','LIKE','App\\Models\\Settings');
```

Database column value format is 'App\Models\Settings'

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = User::where('linkedModel','App\Models\Settings')->get();
```

or

```
$data = User::where('linkedModel','LIKE','App\\Models\\Settings')->get();
```